# How does the sender decrypt his own encrypted message

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa, p2p, end-to-end

I'm working on a chat application where messages will be end-to-end encrypted. To achieve this I'm using RSA key's with the node-forge library. I can now encrypt a message with the public key of the recipient and decrypt it only with his private key. The problem is that I want the sender to be able to decrypt the message they send, not just the receiver. How can I achieve that?

Here I have some example code and the output.

```
var simulateMessageSend = (function () {
            var plainText = "This is a test message that is going to be encrypted. "
            console.log(plainText);

            var encrypted = publickey2.encrypt(this.$forge.util.encodeUtf8(plainText));
            console.log("Encryption: ");
            console.log(encrypted)

            simulateMessageReceived(encrypted)

        }.bind(this))

var simulateMessageReceived = (function (encrypted) {

    var decrypted = this.$forge.util.decodeUtf8(privatekey2.decrypt(encrypted));

    console.log("Decryption: ");
    console.log(decrypted);

}.bind(this))
```

output:
[image]

Comment: Not an crypto expert but using rsa for end-to-end encryption is not a good choice as it has bad message to crypto stream ratio. Consider a symmetric algorithm and the diffie hellman key exchange protocol. A symmetric algorithm would let both parties decrypt messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to "how can the sender also decrypt" is to use a **hybrid** crypto system.

*(directly encrypting with `RSA` is not a good idea as there will be data loss should you encrypt a data payload larger than the modulus `n`, where the modulus is the product of the two primes `p` and `q`, for `RSA-2048` we use two `1024-bit` prime numbers, for `RSA-4096` we use two `2048-bit` prime numbers).*

Instead,

1. generate a strong, high entropy symmetric key.
2. encrypt the payload with this symmetric key using a modern symmetric cipher.
3. encrypt the symmetric key using **each** recipients public `RSA` key (in this case the sender and receiver).
4. attach the encrypted symmetric key to the payload, send payload of encrypted message + encrypted symmetric key(s).
5. recover symmetric key(s) with each private key counterpart.
6. use symmetric key to decrypt message.

This is still bad engineering, because:

1. you're not using ephemeral keys, you are using **static:static** `RSA`, (instead one should use temporary keys for each message).
2. don't use `RSA` use `ECC` over a strong curve such as `curve25519`, performing `ECDHE` to agree symmetric primitives for message encryption, (request ephemeral public key, perform ECDHE with your ephemeral private key, dispatch payload with your ephemeral public key so recipient may also use ECDHE with their ephemeral private key to generate ephemeral symmetric key).
3. authenticate with static `Ed25519` keys or `3XDH`.

Overall, strong E2E messaging systems are hard to engineer. Tread carefully if you are using this home-brew solution against a serious threat model.

Please take a read, but if you have further questions don't hesitate to ask below. I'm happy to provide more detail in simple language.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It was really useful. It opened my eyes and I have been doing a lot of research in the direction you pointed me! :)